# Java XSLTTransform to XML incorrect node value

Tags: java, xml, transform, javax

I am having some strange problems transforming XML's. I have a XSLTtemplate to apply over a XML and get the resulting XML.
I have an java proccess to do it and this work fine since 10 years... so the java method is correct, sure. Otherwise, I'm almost sure that the problem is the javax.xml.Transformer api.
I use xml-apis-1.3.04.jar library to do it.
I've checked, with the XSLT and XML source and this webpage: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation and the result it's diferent between the web application page and my java process. I'm going show that:

The problem is in a concrete node of a XML and with a String to Number conversion. 
The XSLT node:

```
<Sold>
                        <xsl:attribute name="amountCurrencyID" namespace="">EUR</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string(number(string($var4_resultof_first/*[local-name()='Sold' ])))"/>
                    </Sold>
```

The source XML:

```
<Sold>1064623.94</Sold>
```

Well, apply de xlst with source xml and.... both results, in java (incorrect) and top mentioned webpage (correct):

JAVA:

```
<Sold amountCurrencyID="EUR">**1.06462394E6**</Sold>
```

WEBPAGE:

```
<Sold amountCurrencyID="EUR">1064623.94</Sold>
```

The winner is the WebPage because the correct value must not have the Exponential (E6) 'indicator'. This 'indicator' fu** me in other java method.

In fact, Could be the library to transform the problem? I think the XSLT isn't the problem, if in the webpage is correct? What's the point?

The javaCode do that is:

```
public void convert() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, TransformerException {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();

    Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.getUserInfo().getXslt()));
    // creamos la plantilla en si
    Templates templates = transformerFactory.newTemplates(xsltSource);           

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // preparamos la entrada
    Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(getBais());
    // preparamos la salida
    Result result = new StreamResult(getBaos());

    // creamos un transformador y hacemos la transformacion
    Transformer transformer = templates.newTransformer();
    transformer.setErrorListener(new XsltErrorListener());

    if(this.getParametros()!=null && this.getParametros().size()>0){
      String nombre="";
      for (Enumeration enumer = this.getParametros().keys();enumer.hasMoreElements();){
          nombre=(String)enumer.nextElement();
          transformer.setParameter(nombre, this.getParametros().get(nombre));
      }
    }

    transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);

}
```

Can anyone help me? 
thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: XSLT version perhaps? Besides that, both numbers are equal.

Comment: Mathematically yes, they are. But in Java/Code 
mathematical theory can not always be applied. I don't think the problem is XSLT version, in online web tool works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Use <s>`<xsl:number>`</s> `format-number()` to convert a number to string with a specific format you'd want.

Better yet, don't convert a string to number then back to string. Take the original string directly.

If your number is not an integer, then XSLT/XPath offer no guarantee on what will be the number format when just implicitly converting a number to string. And considering your number represent money, you should have assumed so and looked for a way to ensure how will your number be formatted. It will only do what you assumed in specific cases that you did not test outside of. While I agree that your library's strategy for formatting is surprising, there are tons of cases that would give poor result no matter the XSLT library with your code. You're outputting money amounts, specify a number format explicitly. Always the case in computing.

Edited: Except the correct way to format a number is `format-number()`. `<xsl:number>` has a different purpose.

Comment: Could be a solution, of course, but: Why with java is incorrect and in the online webApp tool conversion is fine? if the xlst is no correct, is no correct for both, java or anything as well .....

Comment: No result you're showing is incorrect. You just don't like the one you get with your Java example. Results are different, and all correct. Like I said, XSLT/XPath make no guarantee about the number format you might get. They do need to respect a few "obvious" features, and both results do respect them all. Like I said, with your online tool you'd have results you don't like too, if you tested with a more thorough set of values. You just stopped at the one problem you noticed with this one 1064623.94 value. There are other problems, which would show in any XSLT engine.